# full text ranking

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to have ranking based on how many words match user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679751/how-to-have-ranking-based-on-how-many-words-match-user-input)

How can I have a search engine ranked by amount of words that are typed in and ranked by the amount of types they crop up in the fields title, description, keywords, link.

So the higher results are ordered by having more of the words that the user submitted. Say if the user typed in iPhone, iPhone key word crops up in the link, description and title field, so that would be ranked higher than say Apple which mentions it only in the description and Apple Store which mentions it in the title and the description.

My code is below:

```
 $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

 $terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
 $i = 0; 
 foreach ($terms as $each) {
  if ($i++ !== 0){
        $query .= " AND "; 
  }
  $query .= "Match(title, description, keywords, link) Against ('".implode(' ',$terms)." IN BOOLEAN MODE') ";
  } 
  $secs = microtime();  



$query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));

echo '<p class="time">Qlick showed your results in ' . number_format($secs,2) . ' seconds.</p>';     

 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title1 = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            $rank = $row['rank'];
          $title = substr($title1,0,60);

        echo '<h2><a class="ok" href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></h2>' . PHP_EOL;
                    echo '<p class="kk">' . $description . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;            
                    echo '<p><a class="okay" href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;
                      }
```

Comment: Is this different to the previous question you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679751/how-to-have-ranking-based-on-how-many-words-match-user-input

Comment: it is much simpler and i don't know how to delete questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure it is possible to implement this within mysql, a full-text search index like [solr/lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is designed to handle this stuff directly. You might find better resources & help going down that road.

Using php, copy the array returned by the mysql query:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ 
 $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then you can loop over $rows and assign a score to

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
  $row['score'] = score_row($row, $terms)
```

score_row is a helper method that returns a bigger score depending on which columns have which terms and your definition of "importance".

Then sort thw rows by score, then print the results as you were doing.

Comment: i would rather find out the mysql implement methd

Comment: The fundamental operation you are interested in is sorting. If you must use sql, then part of your query must use the 'order by' clause like `order by X` , where X is a computed value that reflects the weights you want on each field. If you are willing to do this in php after the results are fetched, or even within javascript on page load (assuming you have an html client), you'll probably end up writing something that's a bit more digestible.

Comment: any ideas where to begin? a place to direct me?

Comment: Sure. Have you had succeeded yet in executing a simple sql query from php? Perhaps the query you stated above. Have you been able to get results back from the database?

Comment: i mean see for yourself at http://www.theqlick.com

Comment: ok, nice! can you update/elaborate on the code above to include the part where you get the results of the executed query?

Comment: i have updated the code above

Comment: any ideas how i can do my task mentioned in the question with that code?

Comment: is the while loop a seperate loop or is it extra field to add to my current loop?

Comment: You must set the extra field in a loop separate from the loop that prints the results because you need to sort them first.

Comment: can the foreach loop go anywhere?

Comment: Call to undefined function score_row()

Comment: ya, you have to write that function so that it returns the score you want, given the terms and the row. something like, if the terms show up in the description & title & keywords, the score is 3, but maybe the score is 2 if the term shows up in just the title and the description... take a stab at it and I'll give you some feedback...